# HttpURLConnection timeout on long polling (comet) - android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, comet

I'm trying to retrieve a json string from a comet URL link.

Here is the API link: http://www.plurk.com/API#realtime
Here is the description:

> You'll get an URL from /APP/Realtime/getUserChannel and you do GET requests to this URL to get new data. Your request will sleep for about 50 seconds before returning a response if there is no new data added to your channel. You won't get notifications on responses that the logged in user adds, but you will get notifications for new plurks.

I was able to obtain the comet_server url and paste that to firefox and get the result manually. However, when I tried to get these json string in android, I only got timeout error.

> 01:48:51.698      com.net.xerothermic.plurk   INFO    PLURK   http://comet58.plurk.com:80/comet?channel=...&offset=0
>
> 01:53:43.680        com.net.xerothermic.plurk   ERROR   PLURK   HTTP con. get
>   response error:Connection timed out

Here is the code I used to retrieve the data.

```
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Log.e("PLURK", "HTTP con. open error:" + ex.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
    try
    {
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    }
    catch (ProtocolException ex)
    {
        Log.e("PLURK", "HTTP con. set method error:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try
    {
        return conn.getResponseMessage();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Log.e("PLURK", "HTTP con. get response error:" + ex.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

**EDIT:** here is the output from a browser. Did I miss to set some properties? 
[image]

Comment: You probably need to increase the read timeout - since the message you receive explicitly states that the read timed out. Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29) (for instance).

Comment: Yeah, I also think about it. But the default timeout value is 0, which means it should wait forever. From the log, it's indeed took longer than 50seconds to generate timeout (~5min).

Comment: @Jens You're correct! Although the default timeout values were set to 0, I still need to set the timeout value manually. After I set them to 70000 (70sec), the program ran successfully. Oddly, the same code run on PC doesn't have these behavior and I didn't need to set the timeout value.

Comment: Yup, Android doesn't always do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the timeout value was set to 0 by default (meaning wait infinitely), I found I still need to explicit set the timeout value in order to not raise IOException.

```
setConnectTimeout(70000);
setReadTimeout(70000);
```

This is only needed on android but not Windows...

Comment: I think it's just not stable. I will need to try a few more wifi spot to draw a conclusion...

Comment: For people who are interested in this issue, make sure you set the web callback URL in the application, i.e. Twitter. I'm not sure why it's necessary, but once I set it, it works without much issue.